# window.location.hash places active class on current anchor rather than nav anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following in place whereby if I click on a nav item with the anchor `#home`, `#about`, etc. it scrolls to the next section and sets the nav item class to `active` which is great.

Now I have added a "go to about section" button in my content on the home section which has anchor `#about`. It takes me to the section but sets the **actual button** to `active` class rather than setting the **nav item** `#about` to `active`.

My comment inline below - just wondering how I can go about this. Thanks!

```
   $(function() {
    var $sections = $('section.section');

    $sections.each(function() {
        var $section = $(this);
        var hash = '#' + this.id;

        $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').click(function(event) {
            $scrollElement.stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: $section.offset().left
            }, 1200, 'easeOutCubic', function() {
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
            $('nav#main-nav a').removeClass('active');

            if($(this).hasClass('content-menu-link')) {
                var link = $(this).attr('href');

                //Looks like it should be placed here after removing the
                //active nav item and setting the var link to $(this),
                //wondering how I can select the nav item whose anchor
                //equals the var hash

                $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

  });
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zuzw/. As you can see, if you click on the link in the "home" section, it doesn't change the nav "about" to active. It just sets the link to active. If you click on a nav item it sets that to active which works great, now just a matter of adding a function so if you click on a link outside the nav with an anchor hash of the nav item, the nav item should be set to active not the link class.

Comment: It's really hard to tell precisely what you're trying to do based on the information given. If you could add your HTML markup to the post, and link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with an example, that would go a long way toward getting an answer.

Comment: Sure thing, give me 2 mins.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins: fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zuzw/ (I'll also update the question now with it as well). As you can see, if you click on the link in the "home" section, it doesn't change the nav "about" to active. It just sets the link to active. If you click on a nav item it sets that to active which works great, now just a matter of adding a function so if you click on a link outside the nav with an anchor hash of the nav item, the nav item should be set to active not the link class.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by replacing

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

with

```
$('a[href="' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I THINK this is what you're after. I just changed this line:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

to this:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
$('ul li a').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('active');
```

If you want both the parent list, AND its `a` to have the class `active`, then you'd do this:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
$('ul li a').not($(this)).parent().removeClass('active');
$('ul li a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zuzw/2/). Is that kinda sorta what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks but not quite. Your code doesn't add an active class to the corresponding nav item. ie: if you click on that link in my fiddle with anchor "#about" it should then set the active class to the nav item a with anchor "#about".